# Printing Graphs in Python

Tags: python, graph, normal-distribution

I will soon start working on a certain computer science assignment, and one of the things I will have to do is use data from a database (I will use SQLite, and its plugin in Mozilla Firefox), and one of the things which I need my program to output is a normal distribution graph of the grades. It would be nice if you could tell me whether I can create a GUI program that can do that (for now I am using Jetbrains Pycharm Edu) Can someone please tell me how am I supposed to do that, consider me not a total starter in python but not a professional either, thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how to ask questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a GUI for my python app like you. And there are mainly two choices. Either you create a native app using some qt for ex. Or you create a web app. I chose the latter for simplicity and portability.

There are lots of framework out there like [pyramid](https://trypyramid.com). Then using [plotly](https://plot.ly) (or bokeh, etc.) you will be able to convert (HTML+JS) some matplotlib directly into interactive plots.